# Glassfish project doesn't seem to run on Tomcat server

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, glassfish

I have little experience in deployment. Please help.

It shows the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:
type Exception report
message Unable to compile class for JSP:
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

Exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\DFMC\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\apache-tomcat-8.0.3.0_base\work\Catalina\localhost\Majha_Capitals\org\apache\jsp\AdminHome_jsp.java]
The type AdminHome_jsp must implement the inherited abstract method HttpJspBase.getIncludes()

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:467)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:355)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.3 logs.
```

Apache Tomcat/8.0.3

Comment: You have the wrong dependency for your project for the tomcat 8. I am not very famiiiar with Java EE. I have seen this error before, and it has to do with your dependencies. I would focus on the version of jasper.

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish is a full blown Java EE server that supports servlets, JSPs, EJBs, JMS and a lot of other things.

Tomcat only supports the deployment of Java servlets and JSPs. If your web application needs any other Java EE services it is unlikely to work on Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

How is a java file placed at the server? Compile it and put the **class** file instead.
Also check if you are placing the AdminHome_jsp.java at the correct location.